# Hook an event on joomla jform user field

Tags: joomla

How do I hook an event on jform joomla user field?

Field:

```
<field name="jid" type="user"
       label="COM_XYZ_JID"/>
```

Listening to change event has no effect:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery(document).on("change","#jform_jid", function () {
        console.log("Hi");
   })

});
```

Comment: How are you importing your script into rhe head? Are you simply using script tags?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use onchange or onkeyup attribute? Like this:

```
<field name="jid" type="user" label="COM_XYZ_JID" onkeyup="console.log('key up');" onchange="console.log('value change');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to how you're importing your script. To import it to the `<head>`, you can do it like so:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery(document).on("change","#jform_jid", function () {
        console.log("Hi");
      })

   });
');
```

Do also ensure you have jQuery being loaded too.

Hope this helps